# Pandas Dataframe - RemoteDataError - Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to pull data from yahoo finance.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
File "banana.py", line 35, in <module>
    data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2011,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 94, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 77, in read
    df = super(YahooDailyReader, self).read()
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 173, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 80, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 91, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\ll\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 117, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv
```

The error shows up when I read from a .csv file instead of a list of tickers:

This works:

```
for ticker in ['MSFT']:
```

This doesn't:

```
input_file = open("testlist.csv", 'r')
for ticker in input_file:
```

I've even put in exceptions (see below) but still not working:

```
    except RemoteDataError:
        print("No information for ticker '%s'" % t)
        continue

    except IndexError:
        print("Something went wacko for ticker '%s', trying again..." % t)
        continue

    except Exception, e:
        continue

    except:
        print "Can't find ", ticker
```

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
import csv
import sys 
import os

class MonthlyChange(object):
    months = { 0:'JAN', 1:'FEB', 2:'MAR', 3:'APR', 4:'MAY',5:'JUN', 6:'JUL', 7:'AUG', 8:'SEP', 9:'OCT',10:'NOV', 11:'DEC' }

def __init__(self,month):
    self.month = MonthlyChange.months[month-1]
    self.sum_of_pos_changes=0
    self.sum_of_neg_changes=0
    self.total_neg=0
    self.total_pos=0
def add_change(self,change):
    if change < 0:
        self.sum_of_neg_changes+=change
        self.total_neg+=1
    elif change > 0:
        self.sum_of_pos_changes+=change
        self.total_pos+=1
def get_data(self):
    if self.total_pos == 0:
        return (self.month,0.0,0,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)
    elif self.total_neg == 0:
        return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,0.0,0)
    else:
        return (self.month,self.sum_of_pos_changes/self.total_pos,self.total_pos,self.sum_of_neg_changes/self.total_neg,self.total_neg)

input_file = open("Companylistnysenasdaq.csv", 'r')

for ticker in input_file:  #for ticker in input_file:


print(ticker)
data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2011,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))
data['ymd'] = data.index
year_month = data.index.to_period('M')
data['year_month'] = year_month
first_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].min()
first_day_of_months = first_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
last_day_of_months = data.groupby(["year_month"])["ymd"].max()
last_day_of_months = last_day_of_months.to_frame().reset_index(level=0)
fday_open = data.merge(first_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
fday_open = fday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]
lday_open = data.merge(last_day_of_months,on=['ymd'])
lday_open = lday_open[['year_month_x','Open']]

fday_lday = fday_open.merge(lday_open,on=['year_month_x'])
monthly_changes = {i:MonthlyChange(i) for i in range(1,13)}
for index,ym, openf,openl in fday_lday.itertuples():
    month = ym.strftime('%m')
    month = int(month)
    diff = (openf-openl)/openf
    monthly_changes[month].add_change(diff)
changes_df = pd.DataFrame([monthly_changes[i].get_data() for i in monthly_changes],columns=["Month","Avg Inc.","Inc","Avg.Dec","Dec"])




t = ticker.strip()                                       
j = 0
while j < 13:

    try:
        if len(changes_df.loc[changes_df.Inc > 2,'Month']) != 0:
            print ticker
            print ("Increase Months: ")
            print (changes_df.loc[changes_df.Inc > 2,'Month'])

        if len(changes_df.loc[changes_df.Dec > 2,'Month']) != 0:
            print ticker
            print ("Decrease Months: ")
            print (changes_df.loc[changes_df.Dec > 2,'Month'])

        j += 13


    except RemoteDataError:
        print("No information for ticker '%s'" % t)
        j += 13
        continue

    except IndexError:
        print("Something went googoo for ticker '%s', trying again..." % t)
        j += 1
        time.sleep(30)
        continue

    except Exception, e:
        j+=13
        time.sleep(30)
        continue

    except:
        print "Can't find ", ticker


input_file.close()
```

Comment: Be careful with so-called "naked" `except` clauses. It looks like you're mixing print statements with print functions. So if this is Python 3 or if you've imported `print_function` from `__future__` you're probably getting a SyntaxError on the final line.

Comment: @ bernie, It's not Python 3. Ran similar code in other program, did not have an issue.

Comment: The fact remains that you cannot mix the two types of `print` calls. If this is not Python 3 and you're not importing `print_function` from `__future__` then you need to consistently use print **statements**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pandas_datareader` throws this error when yahoo does not make data for the `ticker` in question available through its API.

When reading your `.csv` file, you are including newline characters, so `pandas_datareader` doesn't recognize the tickers.

```
data = web.DataReader(ticker.strip('\n'), "yahoo", datetime(2011, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 12, 31))
```

works when I create a file that lists tickers in the first column.

Might be easier to do:

```
tickers = pd.read_csv('Companylistnysenasdaq.csv')
for ticker in tickers.iloc[:, 0].tolist():
```

assuming your file is a simple list with tickers in the first column. Might need `header=None` in `read_csv` depending on your file formatting.

To handle errors, you can:

```
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError

try:
    stockData = DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', datetime(2015, 1, 1), datetime.today())
except RemoteDataError:
    # handle error
```

Comment: I just tested it with putting only MSFT in the .csv file and it still no luck....

Comment: if you do `print(ticker)` after `for ticker in input_list:`, does it show as expected without spaces or other changes to the ticker?

Comment: you're on to something here.....i get the SAME error........Actually it prints the ticker but I STILL see the error show up afterwards.

Comment: it says its on line 40:

data = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", datetime(2011,1,1), datetime(2015,12,31))

Comment: Which ticker is on that line? Chances are that you try the ticker in the online portal and notice there is no 'download historical data to excel' button on the 'historical prices' tab.

Comment: the ticker is AAPL, no way that one doesnt have historical data!

"ticker" links to the tickers inside the .csv. Inside the .csv I put AAPL

Comment: The query runs fine with 'AAPL' and your start/end dates for me.

Comment: See updated answer, there's an issue with how you are reading the `.csv` file, your tickers include newline characters (`'\n'`).

Comment: @ Stefan, It works (I made your changes) but for some tickers it keeps crashing with the exact same error (ex: TFSCU). How would you approach this? I tried using the remotedataerror exception but it does nothing...

Comment: @ Stefan, Great job, much appreciated! There's one last thing, the way I set the date information in the for loop doesn't seem to be working, can you figure out where I messed up? Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind asking a new question where you show how exactly you are setting the date info, and what error message you are receiving? Easier to respond that way.

Comment: @ Stefan. There's no error message, I'm just not getting accurate returns based on how the dates are set up.

Comment: If it's not about the `RemoteDataError` but about what is going on where you iterate through your data, you should ask a new question as this is a bit beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: @ Stefan, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929068/python-pandas-dataframe-data-not-matching-source

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
   You open the file but didnt `.read()` on it.

```
 input_file = open("testlist.csv", 'r').read()
```

Please run these:

```
input_file = open("Companylistnysenasdaq.csv", 'r').read()
for x in input_file: print x

input_file = open("Companylistnysenasdaq.csv", 'r')
for x in input_file: print x
```

Comment: please see edit and add results top few line to question.