# Pandas DataReader handle RemoteError yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am using the below code to parse a large tickers list to yahoo datareader, I am trying to get back a dataframe as per below. If the list is large, I often get a RemoteError back but on different tickers each time. I am not sure how to handle the RemoteError and I am happy to drop the ticker and continue with the next ticker in the list. I would, however, like to try again to get adj close ticker data. I thought using a for loop and adding a time delay would help with yahoo requests but I am still getting a Remote error. Any ideas?

```
 IBM   MSFT   ORCL    TSLA   YELP
Date                                           
2014-01-02  184.52  36.88  37.61  150.10  67.92
2014-01-03  185.62  36.64  37.51  149.56  67.66
2014-01-06  184.99  35.86  37.36  147.00  71.72
2014-01-07  188.68  36.14  37.74  149.36  72.66
2014-01-08  186.95  35.49  37.61  151.28  78.42

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import time
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError

Which_group = ['Accident & Health Insurance'] ##<<<<put in group here
df = pd.read_csv('/home/ross/Downloads/UdemyPairs/stocks1.csv')
df.set_index('categoryName', inplace = True)
df1 = df.loc[Which_group]
tickers = df1.Ticker.tolist()
print(tickers)



#tickers = ['SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'] # add as many tickers
start = dt.datetime(2013, 1,1)
end = dt.datetime.today()

# Function starts here
def get_previous_close(strt, end, tick_list, this_price):
    """ arg: `this_price` can take str Open, High, Low, Close, Volume"""
    #make an empty dataframe in which we will append columns
    adj_close = pd.DataFrame([])
    # loop here. 
    for idx, i in enumerate(tick_list):
        try:
#        time.sleep(0.01)
            total = web.DataReader(i, 'yahoo', strt, end)
            adj_close[i] = total[this_price]
        except RemoteDataError:
            pass


    return adj_close

#call the function
print(get_previous_close(start, end, tickers, 'Adj Close'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at this question. This proposes a solution that it might work for you.

[Pandas Dataframe - RemoteDataError - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794095/pandas-dataframe-remotedataerror-python)

Comment: I did actually use that post to help me with the code i wrote above but i still get the issue. I did however use my 4G mobile phone to run above code and it worked fine. It only seems to bring up the RemoteError when i use the wifi at home!!! Aussie broadband...we rank pretty low in the world.

Comment: Yeah probably is a network issue maybe timeout. In the **pandas-datareader** github there are plenty of issues regarding the yahoo finance endpoint. Do you still get the error or the `except: RemoteDataError ` catches the error (if so instead of pass you could use **continue**).

Comment: It seems to catch the RemoteDataError ok, but now i get a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Comment: Maybe when the RemoteDataError is raised the loop tries it again and it might try to read data that is already assigned to a specific index and that would raise that ValueError so you could try an if to check if that **i** index is already set and if it is, replace it or something.